# How to read the values of a dropdown using Jxl API

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, jxl, jexcelapi

I have an Excel sheet in which 2 columns have a dropdown with one about 4-5
values and the other with 2 values that can be selected. I would like to read
the value that is there for each row in these two columns. . What is the code
sample to do that? I did browse a while on the net and this forum, but did not
find any answers. I posted in the JExcel Yahoo groups , but no success. 
I have added the following code, but this does not help. This code sample just prevents the "common Assertion failed" error

```
 WorkbookSettings settings = new WorkbookSettings();
  settings.setSuppressWarnings(true);
 Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(sis, settings);
```

The sheet gives an erroneous row count when the dropdown is there. Has anyone been able to read the values selected in the drop down ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have applied an autofilter to your Excel sheet then probably that is responsible for the issue. I would suggest you to please remove the autofilter and then try fetching the value of the combobox.

```
Cell yourCell = yourSheet.getCell(x,y);
String comboboxValue = yourCell.getContents();
logger.log("value selected in combobx is : " + comboboxValue );
```